# How can we compare excution time in theory and in pratice

Tags: algorithm

So from my understading, we can only evaluate algorithm with asymptotic analysis but when executing a algorithm, it can only return amount of time.
My question is how can we compare those two ?

Comment: You can't. There are some breakthrough algorithms in theory, which are never used in practice because they are too slow. AKS prime-test (practice: probabilistic algorithms like Miller-Rabin), AKS sorting-networks (practice: heuristics) (the name is a coincidence), maybe the Ellipsoid method (practice: interior-point methods) and many many more. The *hidden constants* can kill off any practical usage.It's worth noting, that sometimes this changes over time:interior-point methods got some momentum (still going) when cpu/memory/sparse-matrix software improved.To some extent neural-networks too.

Answer (score 1):

They are comparable but not in the way you want.

If you have an implementation that you evaluate asymptotically to be say O(N^2) and you measure to run in 60 seconds for an input of N=1000, then if you change the input to N=2000 I would expect the run-time to be on the order of 60*(2^2) 4 minutes (I increase the input by a factor of two, the runtime increases by a factor of 2 square).

Now, if you have another algorithm also O(N^2) you can observe it to run for N=1000 in 10 seconds (the compiler creates faster instructions, or the CPU is better). Now when you move to N=2000 the runtime I would expect to be around 40 seconds (same logic). If you actually measure it you might still see some differences from the expected value because of system load or optimizations but they become less significant as N grows.

So you can't really say which algorithm will be faster based on asymptotic complexity alone. The asymptotic complexity guarantees that there will be an input sufficiently large where the lower complexity is going to be faster, but there's no promise what "sufficiently large" means.

Another example is search. You can do linear search O(N) or binary search O(logN). If your input is small (<128 ints) the compiler and processor make linear search faster than binary search. However grow N to say 1 million items and the binary search will be much faster than linear.

As a rule, for large inputs optimize complexity first and for small inputs optimize run-time first. As always if you care about performance do benchmarks.